# how to scan/check java classes in a package for @slf4j annotations

Tags: spring, slf4j, spring-aop

New to groovy and Spring trying to help our Dev team with some logging features in our framework.

I have created a MethodLogging Aspect to log method execution times on any classes with @Loggable annotation.

However, as a second phase I need to determine if a class in a given package is annotated with @slf4j and execute slf4j logging features instead of @Loggable.

here's the aspect code

```groovy
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect {
  // This is a Logging Aspect for the Loggable annotation that calculates
  // method runtimes for all methods under classes annotated with @Loggable

  @Around('execution (* *(..)) && @within(com.zions.common.services.logging.Loggable)')
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    log.info("${joinPoint.getSignature()} executed in ${executionTime}ms");
    return proceed;
  }
}
```

here's the @Loggable annotation code

```groovy
package com.zions.common.services.logging

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

// Logging annotation to be used at class level

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {}
```

Any ideas or resources on how to approach this effort would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In principle intercepting `@Slf4j` would be just the same as for your own custom annotation **if (and only if)** `@Slf4j` would still be present in the byte code during runtime. But in fact it isn't. It has `SOURCE` retention as you can see in the [annotation source code](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/38d6a7198b5714cf3df5e5778a10a76d5301efc1/src/main/groovy/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.java#L62).

Background: The `@Slf4j` annotation is used by the Groovy compiler in order to dynamically create a static logger during compilation so as to save you as a user boilerplate code in your Groovy classes. If you decompile this class...

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class FooBarZot {
  void test() {
    log.info("test")
  }
}
```

... you will see something like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FooBarZot implements GroovyObject {
  private static final transient Logger log;

  public FooBarZot() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    super();
    MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
    this.metaClass = var2;
  }

  public void test() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    var1[0].call(log, "test");
  }

  static {
    Object var0 = $getCallSiteArray()[1].call(LoggerFactory.class, "de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.FooBarZot");
    log = (Logger)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var0, Logger.class);
  }
}
```

Consequently, AspectJ will not help you intercept the `@Slf4j` annotation just because it does not exist during runtime. You will need to find another way of achieving what you want. One such approach might be annotation processing because it is done before compilation.